# Запись видеопотока с камеры сразу в сеть на Android

Tags: android, видео

Поставил себе задачу - написать приложение, пишущее видео сразу на сервер (под Android ничего не программировал, хочу начать).
Просьба подсказать - с какой стороны подойти к задаче.
Если есть подходящие исходники в сети, ткните в них плз.